# OVS Bridge Connectivity using GRE Tunneling

Tags: sdn, tunneling, openvswitch

Okay so I'm trying to connect two OVS Bridges in separate hosts using GRE Tunneling. A VM is connected to each of the two OVS Bridges.

The problem is that I don't want to add eth0 to the bridges and don't want to give an IP Address to the bridges. The VM's have been given static IP's.

I've tries using multiple online tutorials. But what they all do is add eth0 to the bridges or etc which is of no use to me.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add `eth0` to the bridge.

You also do not have to give your bridge an IP, just set it to `inet manual` (or an equivalent in your config).

Could you please provide your current config? It would make much easier to give an advice.